# Permission to Heroku Denied to Github Repo

Tags: heroku, github

I am pushing an simple application to Heroku using "git push heroku master", then I also want to push the code to github using "git push origin master". However, I got a problem like this:

> remote: Permission to heroku/node-js-getting-started.git denied to
>   github. fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/': The requested
>   URL returned error: 403

So, my question is if I push app to heroku first, then I do not have permission to push to github? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at this step by step:

1. you clone the repo (which belongs to heroku)

this sets an `origin` remote which you can pull from.

2. you push to heroku

this involves setting a `heroku` remote which you can push & pull to.

In order to push to git, you'll need to fork the repo or just create a new repo and point your `origin` to it.

These are the steps:

1. create a new repo on github, copy the url
2. `git remote set-url origin <paste the url>`
3. `git push origin master`

403 means permission denied.